# Where was call made so I can manage exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, exception, webforms

I have a webform with button `ButtonAdd`. I click on `ButtonAdd` and event handler `ButtonAdd_Click()` is invoked.

This sequence of events breaks in `ClassX`, and has method `ReturnResults()` that looks like this:

```
public DataTable ReturnResults(string ConnectionString, string Employee)
{
    DataSet projects = new DataSet();
    string sqlSelect = string.Format("usp_ReturnEmplData '{0}'", Employee);
    try
    {
        nsbProject = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, sqlSelect);
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    DataTable empTable = projects.Tables[0];
    return empTable;
}
```

`ReturnResults()` is not called directly from the webform, but I don't know who exactly called this method.

So now the debugger hits `throw;`, pressing `F11` ("step into") takes me to the web browser with the unmanaged error.

I assumed that by throwing the exception the debugger would take me to the previous class that called `ClassX.ReturnResults()`, and so on, until reaching the webform. But that's not happening. As soon as `throw;` is hit, I get the unhandled error in the webform, and that's exactly what I want to avoid.

My question is: how can I see all the calls (between `ButtonAdd_Click()` to `ReturnResults` without having to debug the button click?

Comment: Look at the stack trace in the exception object.

Comment: Note that there's no point in catching an exception if the only thing you're going to do is throw it again. Generally you catch an exception because you can handle it in some way, or because you want to add more details to the exception and rethrow it, or because you want to log the exception details where you have more context and rethrow it.

Comment: Also note that passing DataTables around makes your app brittle, hard to work with, and less efficient than it should be. Have you considered creating classes to represent your data and passing those around instead? This is made considerably easier via ORM's such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: @KennethK., thanks. That worked.

Comment: I log the exception, I just didn't include it in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kenneth K mentioned, looking at the stack trace in the exception object will display all the previous calls made to reach the call where the call was made.

Something that I just realized is that the last method was the only one with the `try-catch statement`, which means that `throwing` or `rethrowing` the exception will do no good since the previous call did not have `try-catch statement`.